# Manufacturer specific layout override in Opencart

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

In Opencart it is possible to apply layout override on category and products. What I need to do is to apply layout override on manufacturer page. But I found there is no such option in current Opencart version. Any advice how it can be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: I guess the only way of how to achieve this is to *re-implement* the same feature to manufacturers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a modification for OpenCart called [custom templates](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8056&filter_username=JAY6390) that allows you to do this. Other than that, there's no way to change the template per manufacturer (This modification also allows you to do the same for products, categories and information pages too)